# How to present an Android project when only the layout has to be done

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to make a new design for an Android App, but I only have to create the visual part (native Android). The app logic would be created by another guy based on what I present to him.

My question is? How would this be managed correctly? Do I have to make the XML's of each layout? How could I show the other person my progress?

What things should I consider when doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Google provides lots of resources for mocking up an app before coding it. There are photoshop docs, icons, UI mockups, etc. See http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mock the app first (create a prototype) as suggested by NoChinDeluxe. Then if you guys go ahead and decide to code it, the answer to your problem is separation of responsibilities. As Jeffrey said UI work is not only about layouts, but code as well. What I would suggest is that you and the other guy get together first and define some contracts (interfaces) that will allow you guys to split the work and work in parallel. Therefore, he can create the business logic of the app without worrying about the UI implementation. You, on the other hand, will have to mock that business logic he's implementing at the beginning so it doesn't block your UI work.

Answer (score 0):

you could create layout XML files for all the Activities/screens, using resources (icons, etc as suggested by @NoChinDeluxe). However since you'd want to run the mock app, you might want to also create a "throw-away" Activity that allows you navigate to different screens of the app. Here you can add a number of buttons and when you click on each button, your app shows a specific activity. This way, you will be able to show your colleague all the screens you have created. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you want to hear, but creating Android layouts isn't a design task. They are closely tied to the code, and the design of them is going to depend on how the engineer chooses to implement the app.

Here's an example. You might have a grid with 4 cells. You could use a `RelativeLayout`, a `LinearLayout`, or `GridLayout`, or a `GridViewLayout`. Which will use choose?

I'd suggest providing your engineer with mockups and graphical assets where required. Let him / her take those and create the layouts. If you want to create layouts as a (visual-only) reference for engineering, great, but it's certainly a non-optimal tool for that task.

Answer (score 0):

Things You will consider when doing visual part:-

You have to work on the **resource** folder of your application

- Layout : All Layout you have to prepare.
- Drawable : Images and drawable .xml.

***Inside Values folder you will find***

dimen.xml : For different devices dimen you can set.

string.xml : You can store string for hint or other purpose.

style.xml : For designing or theme or custom design.

color.xml : Color which are going to used in the application.